# Reorder columns of a dataframe based on max length of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so :

```
| emp_id | name       | address              | zipcode |
|--------|------------|----------------------|---------|
|   1234 | Jack Black | 123 at abc shore xyz | 12345   |
|   1233 | John Wick  | 321 at  xyz          | 54321   |
|   1232 | Sam        | 321 at  xyz at qrst  | 54311   |
```

I want to rearrange the columns, based on the max length of string in each column.
In the above example, address would have the hight max string length(length 20 in row 1), and say emp_id has max length as 4 (when converted to string ).
I need to rearrange the columns based on this max length(descending), post which, the table must look like the following:

```
| address              | name        | zipcode | emp_id |
|----------------------|-------------|---------|--------|
| 123 at abc shore xyz | Jack Black  | 12345   |   1234| 
| 321 at  xyz          | John Wick  | 54321   |   1233 |
| 321 at  xyz at qrst  | Sam         | 54321   |   1232 |
```

Is there a way to do this for any random number of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `assign()`+`sort_values()`+`drop()`:

the idea here is to typecast whole dataframe to string(for getting the max length your original dtypes in dataframe remains same) and then calculate string length of each column and find the max number of length and sort according to it and after sorting drop that column:

```
df=(df.assign(s=df.astype(str).applymap(len).max(axis=1))
      .sort_values('s',ignore_index=True,ascending=False).drop(columns='s'))
```

OR

as suggested by [`@mozway`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway):

```
df=df.loc[df.astype(str).applymap(len).max(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index]
```

OR

Another possible way is to reindex the index after sorting:

```
df=df.reindex(df.astype(str).applymap(len).max(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sum` instead of `max`?

Comment: Also, I imagine you could skip the assign/drop by doing something like `df.loc[df.astype(str).applymap(len).max(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index]` (untested) +1

Answer (score 1):

Convert all the columns to string, then `applymap` to get the length of the strings, call `max` to get maximum out of it, sort the maximum length values in descending order, and take the index.

```py
cols = df.astype(str).applymap(len).max().sort_values(ascending=False).index
#cols
Index(['address', 'name', 'zipcode', 'emp_id'], dtype='object')
```

Then re-order the dataframe based on this column index:

```py
df.loc[:,cols]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                address        name  zipcode  emp_id
0  123 at abc shore xyz  Jack Black    12345    1234
1           321 at  xyz   John Wick    54321    1233
2   321 at  xyz at qrst         Sam    54311    1232
```